# directory not empty message after get latest

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008, tfs

Environment: Visual Studio 2008 and Team Foundation Server 2008

I am getting a "Cannot delete because directory not empty" message after doing a Get Latest. Any ideas why?

Comment: Any hidden files in the dir?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's say you have a folder on disk named fold that has two files in it, foo.txt and bar.txt, like this:

```
fold
    foo.txt
    bar.txt
```

Now, let's say that foo.txt is checked into source control and bar.txt is just a file that you have on your local disk that TFS does not know about (i.e. it has never been checked in and you don't have a pending add on it).

Now, let's say that a member of your team deletes fold and then you run "Get Latest".  TFS sees that it should delete fold and foo.txt from your local disk.  However, it also notices that bar.txt (a file it does not know about) is under fold.  At this point, TFS realizes it cannot delete bar.txt because it doesn't want to delete a file from your disk that cannot be recovered.  So, it deletes foo.txt and leaves bar.txt.  Since it cannot delete bar.txt, it cannot delete fold and thus gives you the warning that it couldn't be deleted.

Answer (score 1):

Use the Source Control Explorer with the administrator account and see what is left inside the folder on the source controler. All the items that is not commited to be deleted can cause this problem. After check in the pending changes, do the get latest thing on the project (not the folder) again. Everything would be fine then.

Cheers